# How to stop puppy biting?

Tags: dogs, behavior, new-pets

It's a common problem I have seen in new puppies. It's a big problem for dog owners to deal with it.

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour] and have a look at the [help]. We're always happy to welcome new members to our community.

Answer (score 2):

First see, why does puppy bite?

There are a couple of reasons that puppies may chomp. The most well-known one is that they're interested, and this is another approach to investigate their reality. They're additionally prone to bite things in the event that they're getting teeth as a method of calming the inconvenience.

They may likewise nip energetically at one another or you now and again. Nipping isn't a sign of hostility; it's simply that the little fellers don't have a clue about any better.

At times little guys may turn to biting out of dissatisfaction, or when they're scared. On the off chance that they go before the nibble by a snarl, they ate you since you disregarded a warning.

Now let's see, **how to teach puppy to stop biting?**

There are several ways which can help dog owner to stop their puppy to bite:

• ***Divert*** :
Redirection takes some arranging. In the event that your puppy attempts to bite you, pull your hand away before he gets an opportunity. At that point give him a treat or toy to divert his vitality to.

• ***Play Games***:
There are some proven games that you can play with your puppy and build trust with fun, with this method you can also [train your puppy](https://dog-training-se.launchaco.com) by yourself.

• ***Distraction***:
Picking the privilege toys gives your little puppy something to bite. A toy that permits you to shroud a treat inside functions admirably here. Pick toys that make your little guy buckle down intellectually too

• ***Prevention*** :
You can likewise discover items that taste awful to demoralize your dog from chewing. Spot a tad bit of the item on a cotton puff and offer it to them. They'll spit it out and smell it. Presently you'll have to apply the item to the things you don't need him to bite.

**Final thoughts**

With regards to preparing your little puppy, tolerance, and uplifting feedback are the keys. Yelling at your puppy, or punishing them when they bite will harm their trust in you. Encouraging feedback, then again, is much more successful.

You must raise an even puppy. Teach the puppy similarly his pack mates would have in nature. On the other hand, utilize past interruption strategies to show the puppy to center that vitality somewhere else.

Show restraint toward him, and he'll before long comprehend what he needs to do.